# no module named flask, but flask is installed

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to run a flask app on my ubuntu server. Everytime I load the page it returns internal server error. The error.log file says that the problem is: No module named flask.
But Im sure its installed. I tried this to install it:

```
sudo pip install flask
sudo apt-get install python3-flask
```

after that didnt worked i uninstalled flask and created an venv. But if i try to install flask there. It tells me `Requirement already satisfied`.
And it still doesn't work. I dont know what i could do now. Maybe u know the answer.
Thanks

Edit:

I can install it with pip3 install flask,
but it still doesnt work. I tried `flask --version` and it shows me the version but the error is still there no module named flask.

Answer (score 0):

Have you activated the virtual  environment ?. If not, cd to the directory of the  virtual env and execute

```sh
source ./bin/activate
```

Comment: i activated the venv

Comment: Replace python in your command by python3. By default, pip refer to pip3 but the python command refers to python2, at least on my Ubuntu installation. Maybe you're running python2, which don't  have flask installed

Comment: Maybe you know what I could do to install flask correctly

Comment: I was saying that to execute your  python script use `python3` instead of `python`

Comment: im not executing the script i use apache2 and wsgi

Comment: And there is no way to control which version of Python they use ? Or you can alias python to python3 instead of python2. I suspect that your problem is that your server is using a wrong version of python.

Comment: but on my sever only python3 is installed

Comment: Stop using sudo and retry ?

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: that happens without sudo ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: and with --user this error comes: ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.

Comment: I do not understand you.`pip install flask ` in your virtualenv returns an error ?

Comment: Yes ```pip install flask``` returns: ```ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click' Consider using the --user option or check the permissions.```